# Column level security in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a list (**Employee Details**) having six columns

- ID
- Name
- Address
- department
- Passport Number
- Mobile Number.

Now, for security purpose I want to hide some columns 
(**ex-Passport Number, Mobile Number**) for specific group of people. How can we achieve this?

Comment: You can't OOTB. However there is a third party solution available at codeplex. https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Comment: Or Create Views and show only views specific to those groups

Comment: If want it to be on form, then you need some customization

Comment: @Gaurravs:  i have created views also. But I am not able to find any option to achieve my task. As I am beginner in SharePoint. So could you please help me out .If it is possible provide me steps.

Comment: @Christoffer: could you explain me what is codeplex?

Comment: @Gaurravs: Thanx for editing my question

Comment: @Christoffer: The link which you have provided me is for SP 2010. But I am using SP 2013.

Comment: @Deepi : do you want to restrict the fields to be shown from form or just view?

Comment: @Gaurravs : anything . My task is just when any user from my restricted group opens the list, he will not be able to see that restricted fields. Thats it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not include scope for list forms.

Steps to achieve this at view level when user moves to list.

1. Create different view based on your requirement. Remove unwanted columns from view.
2. Create a webpart page. Give some relevant name
3. Now Add list view webpart to it.
4. Modify webpart
5. Select particular view created in step 1.
6. In audience target property of WebPart add the concerned group.
7. Click Ok.
8. Now add another list view webpart to same page below or above the previous webpart.
9. Follow step 4-7 again.
10. Save and check-in the page.
11. To test add your ID to any of those group, and see if only that specific webpart is visible. Make sure you are not part of any other group.
12. Once verified, Publish the page.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB way to handle the Column level security. But there is workarounds available for it.

- You can use the custom code to hide it
- You can use the 2 list apporach, Master List and Child list. in child list you can show what you want to show the user from the Master list.

[3 Approaches to Restricting Access to SharePoint Columns](http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata)

- You can use the 3rd party solution, as Bamboo has one.[Column Level Security](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The default view is cut down for the user but I used two different content types and in the workflow email to the approver I used the full set of fields and form ID to select the correct form:

```
https://mysharepoint.com/workspaces/requestleave/Lists/Leave%20Request/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fharmony%2Eatradiusnet%2Ecom%2Fworkspaces%2Frequestleave%2FLists%2FLeave%2520Request%2FAllItems%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0100438359F426C75C4F9C5FFC3017D2B451
```

The user gets a cut down field input view and a final full view after the approval process is completed `https://mysharepoint.com/workspaces/requestleave/Lists/Leave%20Request/DispForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]`

They can edit this afterwards but they can't change mid process.