# Different level permissions on columns than on document in Document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, document-library, permissions

In document library there are several columns that additionally describe document, exp. Status column.
What I would like to do is to set permissions to Read level on document itself and Contribute permissions on columns.

Any advice how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB way to set column level permissions. If user has Read level permission on an item them he will not be able to edit any of its columns. Some possible approaches you can try is -

1. Create a separate List for columns which require Contribute level permission. Add lookup column to List with document library's ID column. Give users Contribute permissions on the list.
2. Give Contribute permission to user on documents and hide fields using JS/CSS on the form.
3. Use third party solutions like [SharePoint Column/View Permission (Boost solutions)](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html)

You can also refer some links over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37828497/1047998), [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/183846/20540) and [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/skype-business/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata).

Comment: Thank you very much on reply. However, for 1st solution I thought of similar thing, but than I realized I will have hundreds, soon thousands of documents across site collection in multiple document libraries. It would maybe suitable if I had only one library. Second option I see no possibility for me as I don't have to hide columns from users instead I want them to be able to edit them, in the end, third party solutions are not an option for me. Thank you once again on your reply!